# How to use gcc with Mac OS X and Xcode?

Tags: macos, gcc

I am using mac os now, I want to use gcc to compile my c program using command line, I have downloaded Xcode and installed the command line tools, but I still can not use gcc to compile my program. when I type: ":gcc xxx.c", the command mode said "not an editor command", but, people from website said if I did what I said above, I can use gcc to compile my program. so, I want to know why I can't use my gcc?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48099/gcc-not-found-but-xcode-is-installed see if this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to perform `gcc xxx.c` from within a VI-like editor.  If so, the proper way to perform a command is:

```
   :! gcc xxx.c
```

With `:!` you can enter all sorts of Unix commands.  In the case of `gcc` you might try `:! gcc -o xxx xxx.c`.  You can learn more (lots more!) with `:! man gcc`

Comment: Your answer worked!! I really thanks about that. But i have another question now. I typed a c program and compiled it, but it didn't work. The command line said "return type of 'main' is not int". Then i copied a program from the internet which the author said it does work. But when i typed:"!gcc xxx.c". it still caused the same problem as my program did. Can you help me about that? thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you install XCode, GCC will run normally on your terminal. In order to open the terminal, go to `Applications > Utilities` and open `Terminal.app`

once there type `gcc [file to compile]` and it will work if gcc is installed properly

If you still can't use GCC in the terminal, try this: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer